# Docker - Communication between two PHP containers: "Connection Refused"

Tags: php, docker, nginx, docker-compose

So, I have a problem with my docker setup for a project I'm working on. Using Docker and docker-compose I have set up a few containers as seen below. I can reach both php services via the browser no problem. dev.drmobile.local refers to the Magento service and dev.dronline.local refers to the Symfony service. The problem is that when the Magento service needs data from the Symfony service, I get an error stating `Unable to Connect to tcp://dev.dronline.local:80. Error #111: Connection refused`. I have tried merging both services in 1 container, but the problem is also present in that situation.

All other communication between containers seems to work fine.

I'm not sure on the port setup I've used, but it doesn't seem to trigger any errors.

Both php containers use the same image created from a Dockerfile, with a slightly different init script.

Any help and tips will be greatly appreciated.

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.3'

networks:
    drmobile:

services:
    nginx-service:
        image: nginx:stable-alpine
        container_name: drmobile-nginx-container
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www/html
            - ./.docker/nginx/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
        depends_on:
            - symfony-service
            - magento-service
        networks:
            - drmobile

    magento-service:
        container_name: drmobile-magento-container
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./.docker/php/Dockerfile
        ports:
            - "9000:9000"
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www/html
            - ./.docker/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
            - ./.docker/php/magento/docker-install.sh:/var/www/html/docker-install.sh
        networks:
            - drmobile

    symfony-service:
        container_name: drmobile-symfony-container
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./.docker/php/Dockerfile
        ports:
            - "9001:9000"
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www/html
            - ./.docker/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
            - ./.docker/php/symfony/docker-install.sh:/var/www/html/docker-install.sh
        networks:
            - drmobile

    mysql-service:
        image: mysql:5.7
        container_name: drmobile-mysql-container
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        volumes:
            - ./.docker/data/mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
            - ./.docker/mysql/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
            MYSQL_USER: dynalinq
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
        networks:
            - drmobile

    redis-service:
        image: redis:2.8
        container_name: drmobile-redis-container
        ports:
            - "6379:6379"
        networks:
            - drmobile

    varnish-service:
        build:
            context: .docker/varnish
        container_name: drmobile-varnish-container
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        networks:
            - drmobile
        depends_on:
            - nginx-service

    elasticsearch:
        image: elasticsearch:1.7.6
        container_name: drmobile-elasticsearch-container
        networks:
            - drmobile
        volumes:
            - ./.docker/data/elasticsearch-data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
        environment:
            ES_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx512m -Xms512m"
            HOSTNAME: "elasticsearch-dev"
```

`.docker/nginx/dev.dronline.local.conf`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/html/symfony/web;
    server_name dev.dronline.local;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/dronline_access.log custom_dronline;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/dronline_error.log;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass drmobile-symfony-container:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

`.docker/nginx/dev.drmobile.local.conf`

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name dev.drmobile.local;

    root /var/www/html/magento;
    index index.html index.php;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/dev.drmobile.local_access.log custom;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/dev.drmobile.local_error.log;

    location / {
        index index.html index.php; ## Allow a static html file to be shown first
        try_files $uri $uri/ @handler; ## If missing pass the URI to Magento's front handler
        expires 30d; ## Assume all files are cachable
    }

    location @handler { ## Magento uses a common front handler
        rewrite / /index.php;
    }

    location ~ .php$ { ## Execute PHP scripts
        fastcgi_pass drmobile-magento-container:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE base;
        fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE website;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the container name instead of the hostname. Docker is serving your `/etc/hosts` file to the containers and is also providing name resolution for the containers in the same network, so using the hostname is causing it to resolve to 127.0.0.1, which, in that case, is the same container.

Comment: You mean using the container name as the request url?

Comment: Yes, connect to `symfony-service:9000` instead of `dev.dronline.local:80`.

Comment: If I do that, I get "Unable to read response, or response is empty". I'm not sure how routing works without the nginx container in between. The URL is `http://symfony-service:9000/api/repairorders/1562/orderstatusoverview`, but I'm not sure if it even reaches the symfony code.

Comment: I _think_ both the service name and the container name should be reachable from one another. You can confirm by opening a session and trying to `ping` / resolve both names: `docker exec -it magento-service bash` and then ` ping symfony-service` or `ping drmobile-symfony-container`. And for connectivity, both are in the same `network`, so they should be able to connect to one another.

Comment: I am indeed able to ping one container from another using both the servce name and container name. It resolves to the correct IP in the network too.